# How to extend span-method for different tables

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I dynamically generate a group of cards. And each card will generate a group of tables. Each table will have different row span effect. I wrote the code below, Obviously, all tables will call the same method objectSpanMethod. I want to extend span-method to add a param to tell different table. How?

```html
<el-card v-for="(f, i) in arrangedflightInDay" :key="f.id" :name="f.name" class="box-card" >
    <div class="clearfix">
        <el-table
            :data="arrangedPlanInDay[i].content"
            :span-method="objectSpanMethod"
            @selection-change="selectionRecords">
            <el-table-column type="selection" width="40">&nbsp;</el-table-column>
        </el-table>
    </div>
</el-card>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Dan!
I find another way to do it. Below code is for the information.

```
:span-method="objectSpanMethod(i)"

 objectSpanMethod(idx) {
  return ({ row, column, rowIndex, columnIndex })=>{
     console.log(row, column, rowIndex, columnIndex)
     console.log(idx)
  }  
 }
```